# Regex Get Text Between 2 Words

Tags: regex, uipath

I need to put one word and obtain the html tag with the word inclusive.
Example:

- Text input: Madhuparna

I need to obtain:

- June 5, 2021 By Madhuparna
- bla bla bla Madhuparna bla bla bla

Test text:

`<p>The entire purpose speed up the process.</p><p>June 5, 2021 By Madhuparna</p>\r\n<p>The entire purpose of a terminal emulator is to imitate how the regular computer terminals perform and allowing the main computer to connect to and use a remote computer through a command-line or a graphical interface. The terminal emulators are known to carry out the functions using the software.</p>\r\n<a>It allows file transfer between the main and the remote computer using SSH (Secure Shell) and also enables the host system to execute applications on the remote system. While it features a graphical user interface, programmers rather prefer the text-based interface to gain more control over all functions and speed up the process.</a><p>bla bla bla Madhuparna bla bla bla</p>`

What I do for now but not work:

```
<(\S*?)[^>]*>.*?Madhuparna.*?<\/\1>|<.*?\/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try the following:

*edit - getting slightly messier now (and quite "hacky")...

```
/<([pali]{1,2})>[^<>]*Madhuparna[^<>]*<\/\1>/g
```

Probably not entirely optimised but does the job as per your sample.

This assumes that the only tags you are encountering (as per your sample) are `<p>` and `<a>` but please update the first capturing group `([pa])` of the regex if needed.

Proof here: https://regex101.com/r/16jjLn/1 - (updated)

The explanation panel on the link above will explain what the regex is doing.

Comment: If i have <li>? what I need to modify? I put [pal] but don't work

Comment: I create this and look good: <(p|a|li)>[^<>]*Madhuparna[^<>]*<\/\1>

Comment: How can I do if I need: Find in text the last word "Madhuparna" then get text from left the first [pali]{1,2} to the last </p> or </li> in the text. 

Text input example:
<li>bla bla bla</li><p>June 5, 2021 By Madhuparna</p><li>Use a remote computer</li>

Result that I need: 
<p>June 5, 2021 By Madhuparna</p><li>Use a remote computer</li>

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested this. It's working well.
Please try this again.

```
/<(\S+)(>| .*?>)[^<>]*Madhuparna[^<>]*<\/\1>/g
```

I have just changed your test text like this.

```
<p>The entire purpose speed up the process.</p>
<p class="test">June 5, 2021 By Madhuparna</p>
<p >The entire purpose of a terminal emulator is to imitate how the regular computer terminals perform and allowing the main computer to connect to and use a remote computer through a command-line or a graphical interface. The terminal emulators are known to carry out the functions using the software.</p>
<a>It allows file transfer between the main and the remote computer using SSH (Secure Shell) and also enables the host system to execute applications on the remote system. While it features a graphical user interface, programmers rather prefer the text-based interface to gain more control over all functions and speed up the process.</a>
<span>bla bla bla Madhuparna bla bla bla</span>
```

This can be applied to all tags.

I'm not sure if this is right for you, but I hope it helps you. :)

Comment: Don't work because select all text and only i need from tag <p> to </p> and contain the selected word: Madhuparna

Comment: You can try again above. If you use attr in a tag, then also works well.
and If you just want only <p> tag, you can use like this.
/<([p])(>| .*?>)[^<>]*Madhuparna[^<>]*<\/\1>/g